# How to transform multiple categorical columns to integers maintaining shared values in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there an easy way to transform multiple columns with shared labels into columns of integers maintaining those shared labels as integers?

Here is what I tried:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(0, "a", "b"), (1, "b", "b"), (2, "c", "b"), 
         (3, "a", "b"), (4, "a", "a"), (5, "c", "a")],
        ["id", "c1", "c2"])

columns = df.columns
columns.remove('id')

indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol="{}".format(col), outputCol="{}_index".format(col)) for col in columns]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)

indexed = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()

+---+---+---+--------+--------+
| id| c1| c2|c1_index|c2_index|
+---+---+---+--------+--------+
|  0|  a|  b|     0.0|     0.0|
|  1|  b|  b|     2.0|     0.0|
|  2|  c|  b|     1.0|     0.0|
|  3|  a|  b|     0.0|     0.0|
|  4|  a|  a|     0.0|     1.0|
|  5|  c|  a|     1.0|     1.0|
+---+---+---+--------+--------+
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
+---+---+---+--------+--------+
| id| c1| c2|c1_index|c2_index|
+---+---+---+--------+--------+
|  0|  a|  b|     0.0|     2.0|
|  1|  b|  b|     2.0|     2.0|
|  2|  c|  b|     1.0|     2.0|
|  3|  a|  b|     0.0|     2.0|
|  4|  a|  a|     0.0|     0.0|
|  5|  c|  a|     1.0|     0.0|
+---+---+---+--------+--------+
```

I imagine that I can extract all the unique values across the columns, build a dictionary and use it to substitute across all the categorical columns. But I wonder if there is an easier way to do it.

My system is:

- python 2.7
- pyspark 2.2.0

### Edit:

I've tried to use the solution proposed by @chlebek. I adapted it for pyspark 2.2.0 and this is the result:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(0, "a", "b"), (1, "b", "b"), (2, "c", "b"), 
         (3, "a", "b"), (4, "a", "a"), (5, "c", "a")],
        ["id", "c1", "c2"])

columns = df.columns
columns.remove('id')

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='c1', outputCol='c1_i')
model = indexer.fit(df)
indexed = model.transform(df)

indexed.show()

model2 = model._java_obj.setInputCol('c2').setOutputCol('c2_i')
indexed2 = model2.transform(indexed)

indexed2.show()
```

The execution gets the next exception (I've omitted part of the output):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-1f8dd5cc9b11> in <module>()
     18 
     19 model2 = model._java_obj.setInputCol('c2').setOutputCol('c2_i')
---> 20 indexed2 = model2.transform(indexed)
     21 
     22 indexed2.show()

[...]


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

I guess that when I use `model._java_obj` I mess something up, but I don't know what exactly. Types for model and model2 are different and AFAIK they shoud be the same:

```
print(type(model))

<class 'pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel'>

print(type(model2))

<class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'>
```

### Edit 2:

I'll add the execution of the solution recommended by @chlebek without adapting for pyspark 2.2.0:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(0, "a", "b"), (1, "b", "b"), (2, "c", "b"), 
         (3, "a", "b"), (4, "a", "a"), (5, "c", "a")],
        ["id", "c1", "c2"])

columns = df.columns
columns.remove('id')

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='c1', outputCol='c1_i')
model = indexer.fit(df)
indexed = model.transform(df)

model2 = model.setInputCol('c2').setOutputCol('c2_i')
indexed2 = model2.transform(indexed)

indexed2.show()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2bbc90b5fdd3> in <module>()
     13 indexed.show()
     14 
---> 15 model2 = model.setInputCol('c2').setOutputCol('c2_i')
     16 indexed2 = model2.transform(indexed)
     17 

AttributeError: 'StringIndexerModel' object has no attribute 'setInputCol'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in one `transform` step. You should train your `StringIndexerModel` on first column `model = indexer.fit(df)` and then use this model with changed in/out columns on second column.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val df = spark.createDataFrame( Seq((0, "a", "b"), (1, "b", "b"), (2, "c", "b"), (3, "a", "b"), (4, "a", "a"), (5, "c", "a"))).toDF("id", "category", "category2")

val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("category").setOutputCol("categoryIndex")

val model =  indexer.fit(df)
val indexed = model.transform(df)

indexed.show()

+---+--------+---------+-------------+
| id|category|category2|categoryIndex|
+---+--------+---------+-------------+
|  0|       a|        b|          0.0|
|  1|       b|        b|          2.0|
|  2|       c|        b|          1.0|
|  3|       a|        b|          0.0|
|  4|       a|        a|          0.0|
|  5|       c|        a|          1.0|
+---+--------+---------+-------------+
    

val model2 = model.setInputCol("category2").setOutputCol("categoryIndex2")
val indexed2 = model2.transform(indexed).show()

+---+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| id|category|category2|categoryIndex|categoryIndex2|
+---+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|  0|       a|        b|          0.0|           2.0|
|  1|       b|        b|          2.0|           2.0|
|  2|       c|        b|          1.0|           2.0|
|  3|       a|        b|          0.0|           2.0|
|  4|       a|        a|          0.0|           0.0|
|  5|       c|        a|          1.0|           0.0|
+---+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

edit:

instead of modyfing StringIndexerModel you can use that first model but you need to change names of dataframe to match col names in indexer model

```
indexed.toDF("id","c1_1","c1","c1_i_1")  
indexed2 = model.transform(indexed)
```

so finally you will get df with columns = `("id","c1_1","c1","c1_i_1","c1_i")` and you can rename them again `indexed2.toDF("id","c1","c2","c1_i","c2_i")`

Comment: Your answer seems to be way, but I try to run it in spark 2.2.0 and it doesn't work. I will edit my question to show the errors I get.

Comment: @ZakaElab  you don't need to call that `._java_obj.`, just `model.setInputCol("category2").setOutputCol("categoryIndex2")` it works for me in python

Comment: I added the execution of the code you proposed without using ._java_obj. , remember that I'm using python 2.7 and pyspark 2.2.0. In the pyspark 2.2.0 documentation, StringIndexModel doesn't have method setInputCol, that's why I resorted to _java_obj

Comment: I see that version in conctructor accepts self, so you can use `model2 = StringIndexer(model, inputCol='c2', outputCol='c2_i')`

Comment: When I do that, I get `TypeError: Method __init__ forces keyword arguments.`. I've looked at the source code of `StringIndexer` and is decorated with `@keyword_only`. Thats why I get that error.

Comment: I have another solution,  instead of modyfing StringIndexerModel you can use that first `model` but you need to change names of dataframe to match col names in indexer model `indexed.toDF("id","c1_1","c1","c1_i_1")

indexed2 = model.transform(indexed)` so finally you will get df with columns = `("id","c1_1","c1","c1_i_1","c1_i")` and you can rename them again `indexed2.toDF("id","c1","c2","c1_i","c2_i")`

Comment: That's one hell of a hack, but it works. Edit your answer adding this solution as the one that works with pyspark 2.2.0 in order to accept it. You have to use handleInvalid='keep' as parameter of StringIndexer in order to handle new values that appear in subsequent columns. Thanks for your help!